# Removing Trailing Whitespace in .txt file

Tags: text, applescript, editor, whitespace

I have multiple text files as sources for iOS app to be loaded in NSArray. Each item is in the new line as such:

```
 item 1
 item 2
 item 3
 item 4
 item 5
```

Before I will use the txt files in project, I want to make sure, there are no trailing whitespace at the end of EACH line. Is there a way to remove those directly from source txt file using Applescript or another method?

The problem is, that I have plenty txt files to go through with quite lot of data in each. It would take ages to clean up the given files.

I can do it in xCode, but it would perform the scan each time the app is used, I rather do it in source and write less code. TextEdit removes all whitespace so the file becomes spaceless which I don't want.

```
 item1
 item2
 item3
 item4
 item5
```

Where to start, please?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Terminal:

```
sed 's/[ \t]*$//' < inFile.txt > outFile.txt
```

Which of course can be done in AppleScript using `do shell script`
And of course can be done in a loop in shell or in AppleScript.
It's a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

[TextWrangler](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/11009/textwrangler) has a "Multi-File Search" feature that can do the job.

With "Grep" enabled, search for `[ \t]+$` & replace with nothing.